# Search database for table with 2 or more specified column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, information-schema

I have the following query that I use very frequently to find a table in a database that has a specified column name:

```
SELECT Table_Name, Column_Name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'db' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'col_A'
```

I'm now trying to find a table that has both of the specified columns in the query (ex: *both* `col_A` and `col_B`). I thought it would have been as simple as just further qualifying the `WHERE` clause, but that was to no avail. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way that satisfies the "2 **or more**" requirement without major modifications:

```
;WITH input(ColumnName) AS
(
  SELECT y FROM (VALUES

  /* simply list your columns here: */

    (N'col_A'),
    (N'col_B')

  ) AS x(y)
)
SELECT t.name FROM input
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON c.name = input.ColumnName
INNER JOIN sys.tables  AS t ON c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
GROUP BY t.name HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM input);
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0642566f5e2759a5c867220bef199eb9)

And FWIW [why I don't use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views).

Comment: I was going to alter my answer to include the count, but you beat me to it (had to drive across town :( )

Comment: i dont mind :) yours is more elegant anyway

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know the database already, this should work for you:

```
select t.TABLE_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    on t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
    and c.COLUMN_NAME = 'col_A'
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c2
    on t.TABLE_NAME = c2.TABLE_NAME
    and c2.COLUMN_NAME = 'col_B'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all column names and tables names that have both columnname you can do

```
SELECT Table_Name, Column_Name,TABLE_CATALOG
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'testdb' AND column_name = 'col_a')
AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'testdb' AND column_name = 'col_b')
```